# Unable to create Ruby on Rails projects in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubymine

- Suddenly I'm **not able to create new projects** properly. When I create a new rails project with Rubymine it creates my files into a subfolder called *3.0.9*. I'm also unable to start my project. The error I get is:

> RubyMine Gem Manager
>   RubyMine has detected that some of the gems required for 'testproject' are not installed
> Install missing gems

So I click on "Install missing gems" I get the error:

> Following gems were not installed:
>   xaws-s3x: No gem satisfying dependency found in remote gem repositories

- If I try to **start the project** it says:

> Error running Development: testproject: Rails server launcher '/home/laptop/RubymineProjects/testproject/script/rails' wasn't found in project

- If I try to put a `rails server launcher` in the folder `script` from another project it gives me a bunch of other errors saying:

> WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Sidenote:

I'm using Ubuntu and it all worked fine a couple of days ago when I was creating projects.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that the server process, for whatever reason wasn't shut-down properly and so is still hanging on the port that it started on. You'll have to kill this, in order restart it again. Assuming that it is consuming the port 3000 (the default port), in Ubuntu you can find its process-id and kill it by the below command:

```
lsof -i tcp:3000 -Fp|tr -d p | xargs kill -9
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It didn't help. I'm still looking for an answer  to this problem.

Comment: Sad :( Okie, what is the problem that is still troubling you? May be we'll split your questions in two parts.

Comment: The solution which karthiks gave was for the issue which you are facing for the "Address already in use" issue. You might want to split the question.

For the first issue, check if Gemfile has the line 

source 'https://rubygems.org'

as Gems will be pulled from this link.